# Add new column from a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame`, in which there a column which is composed of `dict`,  I want to extract all the keys and values and make them as two new columns.

```
   a                 b
0  1  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1  2  {'k': 4, 'v': 6}
2  3          {'z': 3}
```

The output would be

```
   a  k  v
0  1  a  1
1  1  b  2
2  2  k  4
3  2  v  6
4  3  z  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flatten values for list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [(x, k, v) for x, y in df[['a','b']].values for k, v in y.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','k','v'])
print (df)
   a  k  v
0  1  a  1
1  1  b  2
2  2  k  4
3  2  v  6
4  3  z  3
```

EDIT: For general solution working with unique index is possible solution modify with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract `b` column, add new column `idx` by index values, convert to index and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
L = [(x, k, v) for x, y in df.pop('b').items() for k, v in y.items()]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['idx','k','v']).set_index('idx').rename_axis(None)
df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  k  v
0  1  a  1
1  1  b  2
2  2  k  4
3  2  v  6
4  3  z  3
```

Comment: There might be multiple columns like column `a`, which are before and after `b`. I don't think this is a general solution.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - You are right, so answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
>>> df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x.b[0], name='v'))
                   .rename_axis(['a','k']).reset_index()

   a  k  v
0  1  a  1
1  1  b  2
2  2  k  4
3  2  v  6
4  3  z  3
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I created the original data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'b': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2},
                         {'k': 4, 'v': 6},
                         {'z': 3}]
                  })
```

Then, iterate over rows of the data frame, and iterate over the dictionary in Column B:

```
ts = list()

for row in df.itertuples():
    for key, value in row.b.items():
        t = (row.Index, row.a, key, value)
        ts.append(t)

print(pd.DataFrame(data=ts, columns=['Index', 'a', 'k', 'v']).set_index('Index'))

      a  k  v
Index         
0      1  a  1
0      1  b  2
1      2  k  4
1      2  v  6
2      3  z  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the dictionary, `explode` the column and apply the `pd.Series` function to get your result :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"k": 4, "v": 6}, {"z": 3}]})

divider = df.columns.get_loc("b")

# expand dictionary within the `b` column
df["b"] = [tuple(entry.items()) for entry in df.b]

# merge dataframe before `b`, the exploded `b` column, and the dataframe after `b`
merger = (
    df.iloc[:, :-divider],
    df.b.explode().apply(pd.Series).set_axis(["k", "v"], axis=1),
    df.iloc[:, : -(divider + 1)],
)
pd.concat(merger, axis=1)

    a   k   v
0   1   a   1
0   1   b   2
1   2   k   4
1   2   v   6
2   3   z   3
```